# Downloading from FTP with c#, can't retry when fail

Tags: c#, ftp, stream, download

I have an application for download Zip files from an FTP.

Many times I got connection problems while a file is downloading so I have to retry but I can't do it.

When I try to download de file again with this line "reader = response.GetResponseStream();" I got the follow messagge "The process cannot access the file xxx because it is being used by another process". I decided to close the writer stream (memStream) in the catch and sometimes it works but sometimes when I try to get de respose again it doesn't work a give me a time out exception.

Is there an clear way to retry download a file from FTP without errors?

EDIT: I see that I can start download again the first file that fail but when another file fail I can't get the response from the request and gimme the time out

Here is the code:

```
FtpWebResponse response = null;
FtpWebRequest request = null;
Stream memStream = null;
Stream reader = null;
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDestino);

                try
                {
                    request = FtpWebRequest.Create(urlArchivo) as FtpWebRequest;
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftp", "ftp");


                //Now get the actual data
                request = FtpWebRequest.Create(urlArchivo) as FtpWebRequest;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftp", "ftp");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done
                if(totalBytes!=0)  //check if a file failed
                {
                    request.ContentOffset=totalBytes;
                }
                //Streams
                response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
                reader = response.GetResponseStream();
                //Download to memory
                //Note: adjust the streams here to download directly to the hard drive
                //MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                string pathCompleto = pathDestino + @"\" + horaMinuto + ".zip";
                memStream = File.Create(pathCompleto);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //downloads in chuncks
                int bytesAcum = 0;
                while (true)
                {

                    int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {                        
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Write the downloaded data
                        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        totalBytes=+bytesRead;
                    }
                }

                //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
                //downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();

                //Clean up
                reader.Close();
                memStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                totalBytes=0;

            }

catch
{
//something
memStream.Close();
request.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically "resume" in FTP involves requesting the file again from a specific file byte offset.

Looking at `FtpWebRequest` class, the property you need to populate once the connection fails will be the length of your already downloaded buffer and you should set the property `ContentOffset`.

More information on this property at the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. How can I implement it? I have to close both streams and response and them works like if I start again but using te contentoffset?

Comment: There is code under the link to show you how. Yes, you would need to construct new Request/Response object pairs - this is just the way these classes work, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried it and got the same error.
It looks like some connection wasn't closed and when I tried to get a new response it can't be performed.

If I stop running my application and open it again, everything start to work ok.

Comment: How did you close and reopen the connection? Still using the `response` and `request` variables like in the code above? If so, did you call `Close()` on both the response stream and the response before reassigning?

Comment: Yes, I close the streams and response in the try but I can't close the reader stream and the response in the catch(I can't use finally for this reason) because an exception tell me that they are closed.

I tried request.abort() after writer.close() in the catch and it worked!!

Now my problem is trying to resume de download, when I try to unzip I can't because the zip is corrupted. I think I am setting the wrong ContentOffset.

Can u help me?

Comment: You should update the question with the new code that's partly working. ;-)