# How to continue or resume FTP upload after interruption of internet

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am using below code (C# .NET 3.5) to upload a file:

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someweb.mn/altanzulpharm/file12.zip");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FilePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();

Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();
ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ftpstream.Close();
```

But the upload breaks when internet interrupted. Interruption occurs for a very small amount of time, almost a millisecond. But uploading breaks forever!

Is it possible to continue or resume uploading after interruption of internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to resume transfer after a connection is interrupted with `FtpWebRequest`, is to reconnect and start writing to the end of the file.

For that use [`FtpWebRequest.ContentOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset).

A related question for upload with full code (although for C#):
[How to download FTP files with automatic resume in case of disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331133/850848#66154869)

---

Or use an FTP library that can resume the transfer automatically.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) does. With it, a resumable upload is as trivial as:

```
// Setup session options
var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword"
};

using (var session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Resumable upload
    session.PutFileToDirectory(@"C:\path\file.zip", "/home/user");
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe FtpWebRequest supports re-connection after losing connection. You can resume upload from given position *if server supports it* (this support is not required and presumably less common that retry for download).

You'll need to set [FtpWebRequet.ContentOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) upload. Part of sample from the article:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.ContentOffset = offset;
```

---

Internal details of restore in FTP protocol itself - [RFC959: 3.5 - Error recovery and restart](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-24). Question showing retry code for download - [Downloading from FTP with c#, can't retry when fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174874/downloading-from-ftp-with-c-cant-retry-when-fail)