# Resumable Upload in BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, upload, resumable

We are using Google BigQuery and uploading data from local csv file using C# SDK. Can we use Resumable Upload functionality using C# SDK?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779788/how-to-continue-or-resume-ftp-upload-after-interruption-of-internet

Comment: @jdweng We want to use resumable upload in BigQuery similar to GCS resumable upload using c# SDK. This is the link for resumable upload: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#resumable

Comment: You can use the command line.  See : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line

Comment: Are you searching for a solution inside the C# client?

Comment: @rmesteves I want to implement solution using c#

Comment: After reviewing these documentations I understand that this is not possible. Maybe you can try using the API directly. Is it a possibility for you? (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryJob.html) (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.UploadCsvOptions.html)